# Delete a range of elements in array

Tags: c++

```
unsigned char arr[]= "ksd sjdhkd 08923 jh32jk3 323hkgk \34 \34 \er \fd\3 \3df \34f ";
```

Delete range from "ksd" to "\34"
and i want the results like below.

```
unsigned char arr[]= " \34 \er \fd\3 \3df \34f ";
```

Note:

- I don't want to convert it to string.
- I dont want to change the dataType of the arr[],
- I want it to be stay as unsigned char arr[]

Comment: You can use `memmove` to copy the part from the second `'\34'` to the last character (inclusive) to the beginning of the array. Plus possibly zero out the rest (depending on what you mean by _deleting_ characters).

Comment: You can use [std::copy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)

Comment: How do you define the end of your array? Is it zero terminated? or do you keep an independent track of it's size?

Comment: A C-style array is a fixed size.  It cannot do what you have asked since the first `arr` is of a different size than the second `arr`.

Comment: This may be a good time to take a step back and ask _why_ you want to do something like that in the first place; there is most likely a much better approach to achieve what yo need to achieve. If you don’t want to convert it to a `std::string`, convert it to a `std::vector<uint8_t>`, maybe…? Arrays on the stack are frowned upon. Dynamic arrays on the stack are non-standard (and may only work by chance / by compilers’ mercy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the type arr[] is arr[64]; so not possible to directly use the same name and change the value. And \3 should be within a raw string .

If the type is not limited, the following works

```
void test_delete_part_of_an_array()
{
    unsigned char arrStore[] = R"(ksd sjdhkd 08923 jh32jk3 323hkgk \34 \34 \er \fd\3 \3df \34f)";
    unsigned char* arr = arrStore;
    auto result = std::strstr((char*)arrStore, R"(\34)");
    if (result)
    {
        size_t newSize = sizeof(arrStore) - (result - (char*)arrStore);
        unsigned char* arr2 = new unsigned char[newSize];
        arr2[newSize - 1] = '\0';
        std::copy(result, (char*)arrStore + sizeof(arrStore), arr2);
        arr = arr2;
        //Further process and delete of the pointer.
    }
}
```

If use string_view, much simpler

```
void test_delete_part_of_an_array2()
{
    unsigned char arr[] = R"(ksd sjdhkd 08923 jh32jk3 323hkgk \34 \34 \er \fd\3 \3df \34f)";
    std::string_view arrv((char*)arr);
    auto found = arrv.find(R"(\34)");
    if (found != std::string::npos)
    {
        std::string_view arr2 = arrv.substr(found);
        printf(arr2.data());
        //Further process
    }
}

If the type is determined to be char[], we may need constexpr string resolver, it requires some library support.
```